# Reading Arduino sensor data from serial port by Python is not working

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

Trying to read the serial output coming from an arduino board with python. Can not figure out how to connect with "pyserial". Following my code and the error message I'm getting:

```
import serial
import time

i=0
ser = serial.Serial('COM7', baudrate = 9600, timeout= 2)

def getValues():
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    return(arduinoData)

while i<1000:
    print(getValues())
    time.sleep(5)
    i+=1


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SerialException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-d34b4056a66b> in <module>
      3 
      4 i=0
----> 5 ser = serial.Serial('COM7', baudrate = 9600, timeout= 2)
      6 
      7 def getValues():

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     29         self._overlapped_read = None
     30         self._overlapped_write = None
---> 31         super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     32 
     33     def open(self):

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py in __init__(self, port, baudrate, bytesize, parity, stopbits, timeout, xonxoff, rtscts, write_timeout, dsrdtr, inter_byte_timeout, exclusive, **kwargs)
    238 
    239         if port is not None:
--> 240             self.open()
    241 
    242     #  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py in open(self)
     60         if self._port_handle == win32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
     61             self._port_handle = None    # 'cause __del__ is called anyway
---> 62             raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
     63 
     64         try:

SerialException: could not open port 'COM7': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

My question is what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Assuming that's the right port number, it's probably already open - the Arduino serial monitor, perhaps?

Comment: thank you Jason you are right that was the problem, the serial monitor was open.... now all is working. Thanks, appreciate it!